# How to load scss in vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, sass, vue.js

//Vuejs component

```
 <template>
    <form class="form form--login" v-on:submit.prevent="login">
        <h2 class="form__title">Login</h2>

        <div class="info info--error" v-if="infoError">Login failed. Please try again.</div>

        <div :class="{'is-waiting': loader}">
            <div class="form-block">
                <input v-model.trim="username" class="field" name="username" type="text" placeholder="User ID" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-block">
                <input v-model.trim="password" class="field" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-block form__actions">
                <router-link to="/password-reset">Lost your password?</router-link>
                <button class="button button--green form__submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
<script>

<style lang="scss" type="text/scss">
        .is-waiting {
            position: relative;
            transition-duration: .3s;
            > * {
                opacity: .25;
            }
            &:before {
                content: '';
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 9;
            }
            &:after {
                background: {
                    position: center;
                    size: cover;
                }
                content: '';
                height: 64px;
                left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                width: 64px;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

//webpack.config

```
"dependencies": {
    "onsenui": "^2.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-onsenui": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  },
```

My component still doesn't load style correctly.

Please help!!

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward. No linting errors or anything?

Comment: So like you said, it doesn't load. Just confirming if its not applying the styles or not loading in the document at all

Comment: Oh then its a css issue, not a vue issue. Are the classes correct on DOM inspect?

Comment: I know what the problem is, I am actually missing styles - form--login, form-block. That example I referred includes partial code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you configure webpack for SASS compiling its natural that it wont work. If your are using an IDE such as Webstorm it compiles beautifully and shows it in the project folder. In my case i just point it to css file.

In your case try to update your config file as:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: I think if you setup a vue2 project using vue-cli, webpack is by default configured to compile sass

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 Could you please update config file for Webpack 2

Comment: @user1 Are you using vue-cli?

Comment: No, I am not using cli.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit... basic, but check here

```
      </form>
    </template>
    <script>
--->    
    <style lang="scss" type="text/scss">
```

If that `<script>` tag isn't closed, your styles get ignored. This should fill your console with large, red, yelling messages, but I guess not always?